# Tweetinvi namespaces are not recognized although dll's are present

Tags: c#, tweetinvi

I'm using creating a **.Net 4.0** application to post stuff to Twitter using the Tweetinvi API. I can't use packages, so I've downloaded the dll's and added them to my project:

[image: References]

Yet my includes are showing errors:

[image: Includes]

My error console shows:

> Error 423 The type or namespace name 'Core' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Tweetinvi' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)   {...file...}.cs 10  17  ApiProviders

Can anyone tell me why this happens and how I could fix this?

Comment: `I can't use packages` - just curious: Why?

Comment: You know you could make a "private company feed" where you just add the packages which are "allowed" and then use this feed instead of the "official NuGet feed"? You can even do this in a "local 3rd-Party folder"...

Comment: What does it say on the warnings/messages tab?

Comment: Yeah @leppie, I've got: http://content.screencast.com/users/KeesCBakker/folders/Jing/media/b1741277-6ea2-49b7-b6d0-54868f77f248/2014-07-10_1408.png

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker: Seems to be built for .NET 4.5. Change the project target setting :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tweetinvi requires the [`Bcl.Async`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) package. You need to add that too.

Check [all the dependencies](http://www.nuget.org/packages/TweetinviAPI/) and make shure all are installed.

BUT as already said I highly recommend using NuGet for this. If you are not allowed to use the "public feed" you can download the packages and put them in a local folder and add this folder as a new feed in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried downloading the project from the download page?
https://tweetinvi.codeplex.com/downloads/get/852208